# Unexpected token ILLEGAL ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the below error in the console log:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on 7 line (url: ...).
```

If I comment line 7, I get this:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on 8 line.
```

I am using `jquery-2.1.0`.

Here is my code:

```
var main = function(){
   $('.btn').click(function(){
      var sumCalc = $('#fieldname4_1').text();
      var phone = $('#fieldname18_1').text();
      var adminEmail = "thedrgef@gmail.com";

      $.ajax({
         url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
         type: “POST”,
         data: {
           ‘key’: ‘some key here’,
           ‘message’: {
             ‘from_email’: ‘some mail’,
             ‘to’: [{
                ‘email’: adminEmail,
                ‘name’: ‘admin’,
                ‘type’: ‘to’
              }],
             ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
             ‘subject’: ‘subj’,
             ‘html’: ‘<h1>hello</h1>
                <p>dats phone: </p>’ + phone
            }
         }
      })
      .done(function(response) {
             console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
      });
   });
 }

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings cannot be quoted with `‘` (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
) and `’` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) characters. Use `'` (APOSTROPHE) or `"` (QUOTATION MARK).

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, but it looks like your editor is inserting some "fancy quotation marks" (`“”‘’`) instead of the regular ones (`"'`).

Answer (score 1):

You are using curly quotes instead of straight quotes, which JavaScript does not support. Just do a search and replace to replace all curly quotes (`“`, `”`, `‘`, `’`) with straight quotes (`"`, `'`).